# Nomenclature of the following aromatic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the name of the compound $\ce{(C_6H_5)-CH=N-CH_3}$  ?

I doubt,  it is  n-methyl benzalamine . Is it correct ? Besides , what could be other names of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Benzalamine seems to be an ocassionally and formerly used general name for compounds of the formula

$$\ce{C6H5-CH=N(R')R}$$

(where C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>5</sub>- is phenyl; R′ may be H). This name probably came from the fact that they can be prepared by a reaction of **benzal**dehyde with an **amine**:

$$\ce{C6H5-CH=O + R-NH-R' -> C6H5-CH=N(R')R}$$

$\ce{C6H5-CH=NH-CH3}$ could be, in this manner, named methylbenzalamine or *N*-methylbenzalamine. You can also find name α-methylbenzalamine, which would be a different compound, $\ce{C6H5-CH(CH3)=NH2}$

However, according to the IUPAC nomenclature, the compound class is and imine, or aldimine.

The correct name of $\ce{C6H5-CH=NH-CH3}$ would be

- *N*-methyl-1-phenylmethanimine (preferred IUPAC name, 2013)

Also note that there is *cis*/*trans* (*Z*/*E*) isomerism possible.

Answer (score 2):

That is called: N-methyl-1-phenylmethanimine or N-Benzylidenemethylamine or N-methyl-benzaldimine. CAS number is: 622-29-7.