# IUPAC names of imines

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

How to write IUPAC name for this imine compound?[image]

Comment: What do you think it might be?

Comment: I don't have an idea about IUPAC nomenclature of imenes.

Comment: Try this  http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.10400.html?rid=a84a6219-9a90-4a39-a066-8c1d134b4aa3

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/100154/544

Answer (score 2):

You have correctly identified the compound as an imine, which is characterized by the double bond between a carbon atom and a nitrogen atom.

According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069),* imines are named using the suffix ‘imine’ (in absence of characteristic groups having seniority over imines).

> **P-62.3.1.1** All imines are named substitutively using the suffix ‘imine’; the presence of several ‘imine’ characteristic groups is denoted by the numerical multiplying prefixes ‘di’, ‘tri’, etc. When there is a choice for numbering, the methodology described in P-62.2.4.1 for amines is recommended to generate preferred IUPAC names

The cross reference to P-62.2.4.1.3 concerns the choice between two or more parent structures in complex polyamines, which is not relevant in this case.

Thus, the parent structure of the given compound is simply **methanimine.** The corresponding name for the *N*-substituted imine is ***N*-phenylmethanimine.** Further substitution at the carbon atom yields the complete name ***N*,1-diphenylmethanimine.**